# Magento 2, Varnish and logged in users

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish

Using Magento 2 and Varnish 5, varnish works perfectly if you aren't logged in.  But when logged in as a normal customer you get an 80%-90% varnish miss rate.  Is there any way to use data cached in varnish for logged in users?  Here is my vcl:

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 5
vcl 4.0;

sub vcl_recv {
        unset req.http.x-cache;
#testing https redirect
if ( (req.http.host ~ "^(?i)beta.example.com" || req.http.host ~ "^(?i)example.com" || req.http.host ~ "^(?i)www.example.com") && req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "(?i)https") {
                return (synth(750, ""));
        }
#end https redirect testing
}

sub vcl_hit {
        set req.http.x-cache = "hit";
}

sub vcl_miss {
        set req.http.x-cache = "miss";
}

sub vcl_pass {
        set req.http.x-cache = "pass";
}

sub vcl_pipe {
        set req.http.x-cache = "pipe uncacheable";
}

sub vcl_synth {
        set resp.http.x-cache = "synth synth";
    if (resp.status == 750) {
        set resp.status = 301;
        set resp.http.Location = "https://www.example.com" + req.url;
        return(deliver);
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
        if (obj.uncacheable) {
                set req.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache + " uncacheable" ;
        } else {
                set req.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache + " cached" ;
        }
        # uncomment the following line to show the information in the response
         set resp.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache;
}

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 5.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'SSL-OFFLOADED: https'

backend default {
#    .host = "localhost";
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 3600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        #Added to test removing Varnish "Error" page on successful purge
        ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        #End
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }


# Testing not caching WP preview URLs. More in sub vcl_backend_response
    if (req.url ~ "\/blog\/.*\/\?preview_id.*") {
        return(pass);
    }
# End test

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unkown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove Google gclid parameters to minimize the cache objects
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"

    # Remove has_js and Cloudflare/Google Analytics __* cookies.
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");
    # Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
    set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        #return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        unset req.http.Https;
        unset req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED;
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED) {
        hash_data(req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED);
    }

}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 8640000s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    # images, css and js are cacheable by default so we have to remove cookie also
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

# Testing not caching WP preview URLs
    return (deliver);
    if (bereq.url ~ "\/blog\/.*\/\?preview_id.*") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        return(deliver);
    }
# End test
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (miss);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you figure out the cause

Comment: Yes.  Magento 2 has different customer groups.  Varnish caches for each group including guests and logged in customers.  If you don't use customer groups you can modify the Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context class so that the cache identifier is the same.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25543

My development team made the fix which worked perfectly as we have no customer groups.  I don't have details on what they did though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use Varnish caching for logged-in users, but it requires some additional configuration.

By default, Varnish will not cache pages that are personalized for each user, such as those with login information or shopping cart contents. This is because Varnish considers these pages to be unique for each user and cannot serve them from cache.

To cache personalized pages, you will need to configure Varnish to vary its cache based on user-specific information. This can be done using a technique called Edge Side Includes (ESI). With ESI, you can split your web page into smaller fragments, some of which can be cached by Varnish, while others are personalized for each user and are fetched separately.

You can use Magento's built-in support for ESI to implement this caching strategy. This involves setting up the necessary ESI tags in your Magento templates and configuring Varnish to recognize these tags and cache the appropriate fragments.

Keep in mind that caching personalized pages can introduce some security concerns, as sensitive user information may be stored in cache. Therefore, you should take appropriate precautions to ensure that user data is not exposed to unauthorized users.